# Release pipelines not visible on Azure DevOps page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

I can view all features except Release pipelines which is showing empty screen for me as shown below. I have tried different browsers such as Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, both showing empty screen. I have verified that I have full access permissions and Visual Studio subscription also. Let me know if you ever faced such issue and a solution for this. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is the network traffic? Investigate a bit more to find out what's going on on the background.

Answer (score 10):

Been hating Azure Portal because they never cared about how intuitive their UI, menus, and options are. It's very hard to navigate. I just want to rant. Here's how you can enable the Release option:

**Go to organization settings**

- Click the Azure DevOps logo
- At the lower left

[image]

**Turn off Disable classic release**

[image]

No idea why they disabled it by default. It says classic and not deprecated, so it should be visible.

Edit (11/03/23): I've read somewhere that Release will be deprecated in favor of a multi-staged pipeline. That explains. They could have added some notes though.

Answer (score 1):

You could troubleshoot this issue by checking following steps.

- Go to *Organization Settings>>Users page* to check if your [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels), make sure that you are not StakeHolder.
- Go to this *Project Settings>>Permissions>>Users tab* to find you, and check which groups that you belong to. Usually members of Contributors group can freely access to releases page.
- Check if others in the same group have the same issue, or just you have this issue.
- Try this in other computers to check if there are some plugins or extensions which cause this issue.
- If you are behind firewall or proxy, please check if the requests are blocked. You could click F12 to check the browser network requests.

BTW, we find that there are [service events](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history), which might causes this issue, you could monitor it.

Comment: Thanks Edward for the reply. I checked the points mentioned except checking on another computer (as I do it on a VDI using citrix so there is only one computer) & have not checked the firewall. I will check it and let you know.  No one in the team has this issue and even I too was able to view it 1 month back, though no settings changed then.

Comment: You could check this the firewall or proxy. And if you are the only user who encounter this issue, it seems that there are something permission limitation to your account, you could contact project admin to remove you from all groups/teams of this project and then re-add you to its Contributors group to check the result.

Comment: yes i am the only user facing this issue. 
removed and re-added by the admin, but still the same result.
No proxy used. I connect to my VDI through citrix.

Comment: It seems that there exists limitation in your account in the backend, we suggest that you submit this feedback here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem, and then the product support team will investigate your issue in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue from one of VM.
Had to add one more URL (ms.gallery.vsassets.io) to whitelist on firewall