# Why is the "Releases" option missing from Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-releases

I'm trying to create a release pipeline for my Azure DevOps project, but I don't have the "Releases" option under the Pipelines tab. I've checked the project settings and made sure that the "Disable creation of classic release pipelines" option is turned off, but the option is still missing.

I'm using the latest version of Azure DevOps, and I'm a project administrator.

Does anyone know why I might not have the "Releases" option?

Thanks, Armando[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkWiP.png)

I tried to find a solution to the problem of the missing "Releases" option in Azure Pipelines. I searched for solutions online and found a few different suggestions. I tried the following steps:

I checked the project settings to make sure that the "Disable creation of classic release pipelines" option was turned off.
I made sure that I was using the latest version of Azure DevOps.
I checked my permissions to make sure that I had the necessary permissions to create releases.
However, none of these solutions worked. I am still unable to create releases in Azure Pipelines.

I was expecting to be able to see the "Releases" option under the Pipelines tab in Azure DevOps. I was also expecting to be able to create a release pipeline by clicking on the "Create Release" button.

Comment: I'm not sure why. My Pipelines submenu shows "releases", "task groups", "deployment groups" (all legacy) but no "XAML". Releases should really be done through pipelines, not "releases"

Comment: I believe the new YAML-based pipelines in Azure DevOps, does not have the "Releases" option as in the classic UI. Instead, releases are managed within the YAML pipeline itself. Also check if you have covered all the steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802191/release-pipelines-not-visible-on-azure-devops-page

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the **Project Settings -> Settings** with us?

Answer (score 0):

If you miss Release please check if you have [them enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-224-update#new-toggles-to-control-creation-of-classic-pipelines):

[image]

> To improve the security of newly created organizations, we will disable creating classic build and release pipelines for new organizations, beginning next sprint. By default, you'll be able to create only YAML pipelines. In contrast to the classic build and release pipelines, YAML pipelines can undergo code review, provide resource access management and support runtime parameters, enhancing overall security with an extra layer of protection. You can enable creation of classic build and release pipelines in your organization's and projects' settings, using the toggles introduced last sprint.
>
> The changes will not impact existing projects and organizations.

But keep in mind that this is not recommended approach. You should use YAML multi stage pipeline for deployments.